# pymc3 for ARIMAX model

Tags: python, pymc3

I have one observed series as the sum of three latent random series

[image: model equations]

where F and G are explanatory variables. F, G, and O are observed. Is it possible to model this under Bayesian framework (assuming a, b, beta having normal prior) by pymc3?

I know Z can be defined as `pymc3.distributions.timeseries.GaussianRandomWalk`, but how can I define X and Y?